# Is it wrong to not recite uva letzion after shacharis before Aleinu?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, kedusha-holiness

Ok, so i know one can recite kedusha desidra alone most preferably with the trup when davening alone at home. Given the length of Shacharis time though (mines about 31 minutes with 2nd Ashrei and i add Uva letzion its 33 minutes long), i omit it half the time and only recite the 2nd Ashrei and jump to Aleinu. Is that wrong ?

Kedusha desidra was also inserted end of Shacharis for those who missed out on Nakdishach Kedusha in Amidah, and got this second chance to recite it together with hatzibbur, so one davening alone cant recite that kedusha anyway in the amidah, so there's no benefit to recite it again end of shacharis since its a makeup for missing the amidah one with the minyan ?

Comment: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5448d9b5e4b04f35b9269e89/t/5ece1b43d90fcc48f73951c2/1590565704706/Kedushas+Beis+HaKnesses.pdf

Comment: Glad to have you here! As has been pointed out previously: "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi." Your current phrasing "i omit it half the time and only recite the 2nd Ashrei and jump to Aleinu. Is that wrong ?" Sounds very much like a request for personalized advice. I strongly suggest editing your question in order to bring it in line with Mi Yodeya policy. All the best.